# MVC 5 - change password on demo accounts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 demo application that uses asp.net security. Within that application I have 75+ user accounts.

The person who gives the demos left, so I'd like to be able to reset all of the passwords for all of the accounts without having to change the email on each account to my personal email and do them individually where a link would be sent to my personal email.

Is there a way I can type in the user name and new password and use built in `IdentityUser` functionality to reset the password?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your app is in standard MVC5 format, put this ViewResult into the Account controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ViewResult> ResetAllPasswords()
{
    // Get a list of all Users
    List<ApplicationUser> allUsers = await db.Users.ToListAsync();
    // NOTE: make sure this password complies with the password requirements set up in Identity.Config
    string newPassword = "YourNewPassword!";
    int passwordChangeSuccess = 0;
    int countUsers = 0;
    // Loop through the list of Users
    foreach (var user in allUsers)
    {
        // Get the User
        ApplicationUser thisUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
        // Generate a password reset token
        string token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(thisUser.Id);
        // Change the password, using the reset token
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(thisUser.Id, token, newPassword);

        // Record results (extend to taste)
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            passwordChangeSuccess++;
        }
        countUsers++;
    }

    ViewBag.CountUsers = countUsers;
    ViewBag.PasswordSuccess = passwordChangeSuccess;

    return View();
}
```

and set up a new View with ViewBag.CountUsers and ViewBag.PasswordSuccess to check the results.

Then set up an ActionLink pointing to ResetAllPasswords in Account controller and press to go.

Obviously the formatting can be changed (maybe a form with a confirm instead, maybe with an input field to specify the password .. ), but the basic controller code should hopefully be good. And note the [AllowAnonymous] attribute is there just for one-off access - not a good idea to leave it there for anything more than testing!

This should reset all Users to the same password specified in the code.

Answer (score 0):

yes in Account Controller just go to the forget Password function and change that code a little where first of all user search the email id and after that system send a mail to that user .
There just write down a code where user send mail to your specific email id then you can get that link in your account click that link and reset the Password